# How to deliver e-mail correctly to the user associated to the email adress specified using Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix

I have a Debian installation with VirtualMin / WebMin / UserMin installed. Now I want to configure an email account.

I created a new email only user. I could immediately send e-mail from that account using UserMin, but it seems impossible to receive mail.
I checked the user mapping and mapped jordy@example.com to jordy-example.com.

When I send an email, I simply get it back with following message:

```
<jordy-example.com@com> (expanded from <jordy@example.com>): Host or domain
name not found. Name service error for name=com type=AAAA: Host
found but no data record of requested type
```

I set an MX record in my domain's DNS configuration outside of my server.

Can someone maybe give me a hint where to search the issue, since I don't find it on my own. Maybe some resources, similar issues, something to check,... Any help is appreciated.